# Checkbox ArrayList throw PropertyNotWritableException

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am getting "PropertyNotWritableException" upon when i try to set boolean value of checkbox to arraylist checkbox list element.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{trialBalanceBean.chkBoxList.get(0)}" itemLabel="#{loc.fuelstockcards}">
                                <p:ajax update="frmTrialBalance:fuelStockMenu"/>
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

 List<Boolean> chkBoxList = Arrays.asList(new Boolean[]{false, true, true, 
 true, true, true, true, true, true, true});
```

I created Boolean List as chkBoxList then
When i changed the value of checkbox it throws "PropertyNotWritableException" . I think it throws bcz of am using get(0) not set(0,something).Default it must get get(0) so false so unchecked.If user want to change it must be set to true so checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be exactly the behavior you should expect. The Boolean class is immutable, so there is no way for it to work as a backing bean value container.

What you should be using here is the `<p:selectManyCheckBox>` or `<p:selectOneRadio>` components. They are specifically designed to handle multiple choices and incoming arrays of selection items.

For more information on how to use these, you can refer to the PrimeFaces showcase;
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml